# Date Range Picker showing incorrect time

Tags: jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I'm using the plugin [Date Range Picker plugin](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) with some predefined range. I am having some issue to display the correct time.

**What I expect:**

Say it is  `January 28, 2016 17:00 pm`. When I select last 30 minutes, it is showing  `January 28, 2016 16:30 pm` -  `January 28, 2016 17:00 pm`. This is correct.

However, when it is `January 28, 2016 17:05 pm` (5 minutes later), I choose to select `Last 5 minutes`, I expect it to give me the range  `January 28, 2016 17:00 pm` -  `January 28, 2016 17:05 pm`.

**What I got**

`January 28, 2016 16:55 pm` -  `January 28, 2016 17:00 am`

As you can see, it is calculating the date difference based on the time I loaded the page instead of the current time. How can I achieve the result I want?

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga073yr6/9/) for you to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the name of the clicked range in your callback, and compute the times there.

```
function cb (start, end, label) {
  if (label == 'Last 30 minutes') {
      start = moment().subtract(30, 'minutes');
      end = moment();
  }
  $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY h:mm a') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY h:mm a'));
}
```